# Best way of combining meshgrid with matrix multiplication in function

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

With `np.meshgrid` numpy provides a convenient way of plotting functions of two variables, e.g. like so:

```
def plot():
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = plt.axes(projection="3d")

    x = np.linspace(-6, 6, 30)
    y = np.linspace(-6, 6, 30)

    X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
    Z = f(X, Y)

    ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)
    plt.show()
```

Unfortunately, this easy setup interferes with me defining any quadratic function

[image: quadraction function formula]

in the most natural numpy way, i.e. like so

```
def f(x, y):
    vec_x = np.array([x, y])
    return 1/2 * np.dot(vec_x.T, np.dot(A, vec_x)) - np.dot(b.T, vec_x)
```

The problem is that the `meshgrid` arrays `X` and `Y` in `plot()` when calling `Z = f(X, Y)` will now be processed as arrays by the line `vec_x = np.array([x, y])` which results in `vec_x` being a `(2, 30, 30)` shape array instead of an entry-by-entry treatment which would give a `(2,)` shape array **which is what I would want**. Compare this to

```
def other_f(x, y):
    return x + y
```

which works perfectly in a natural way with numpy thanks to the vectorization.

I haven't used numpy and matplotlib for a while but I would really and all workarounds that I come up with feel super clumsy, so, I'd love to see a neat way to work around this.

Comment: So what do you expect `vec_x = np.array([x, y])` would be instead of a 2x30 matrix?

Comment: A (2,) array or a 2x1 matrix if you will. My matrix A is 2x2 and thus the shapes conflict in `f`

Comment: Sorry, my mystake. You are passing `X` and `Y` to `f`. `X` and `Y` are two (30, 30) matrices. Hence `vec_x = np.array([x, y])` returns a (2, 30, 30) matrix. What operation are you looking for to get a (2,) array?

Comment: That's exactly the problem! If my function would not involve matrix multiplication, for example if I had `def f(x,y): return x+y` then, numpy would do everything entrywise and my whole setup would work out of the box, right? But, my function involves matrix multiplication and thus shapes conflict.

Comment: matrix multiplication is done with `np.dot` in most cases. What I don't understand is what `vec_x` should be in your case.

Comment: @PaulPanzer that works exactly as I wanted it. If you could write a short answer maybe explaining briefly why this works, I would accept it :)

Comment: Have done, there was a small mistake in my comment so I deleted it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `einsum` like so:

```
np.einsum('i...,ij,j...',vec_x,A,vec_x)/2 - np.einsum('i...,i',vec_x,b)
```

This is interpreted by Einstein convention as:

```
1/2 sum_ij vecx_i,... A_ij vecx_j,... - sum_i vecx_i,... b_i
```